# How to embed audio file in HTML if it's being sent as octet-stream?

Tags: http, firefox-addon, embed, greasemonkey, mime-types

I'm trying to write a Greasemonkey script that will convert all "Play" links on a page to embedded audio (using the `<embed>` tag).

When I use a link that I get from a GMail attachment, it works like a charm.

When I use a link from another site (Digium Switchvox), the HTTP response header has `ContentType` set to "application/octet-stream" instead of "audio/x-wav" (like GMail's link). This confuses Firefox, which decides that I don't have the right plugin installed. If I set the `type` attribute in the `<embed>` tag to "audio/x-wav", Firefox uses Quicktime to load the file. Quicktime gets confused, however, and won't play the file.

Does anyone know of a clever way to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you configure the server to send the right headers?

Comment: Unfortunately not. This would all be so much easier if I had access to the server.

Comment: You need access to the server. You can't normally override the headers sent by the server; to do so would be a security risk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried [overrideMimeType](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_xmlhttpRequest)?

> overrideMimeType
>   String (Compatibility: 0.6.8+) Optional.
>   A MIME type to specify with the request (E.G. "text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1").